# Get Site column in Site Collection and add it to a SubSite List using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm a complete PowerShell noob and don't really have much exposure with it at all. I've googled for assistance but not having any joy with my specific issue.

I'm trying to get a SiteColumn that exists in a site collection and then apply that same site column to a list on a subsite in the same site collection.

Below is one of the examples i have tried with no joy and the error message below

```
$web = Get-SPSite http://siteURL/

$siteCol = $web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("ColumnName")

$subWeb = "SubSiteURL"
$spList = $subWeb.Lists["ListName"]

$spList.Fields.Add($siteCol)

$spList.Update()


You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:7 char:1
+ $siteCol = $web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("ColumnName")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Cannot index into a null array.
At line:10 char:1
+ $spList = $subWeb.Lists["ListName"]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:12 char:1
+ $spList.Fields.Add($siteCol)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:13 char:1
+ $spList.Update()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Can anyone point me towards the answer please?

Thanks.

Comment: Modify `$web = Get-SPSite http://siteURL/` to `$web = Get-SPWeb http://siteURL/` and `$subWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://siteurl/subsiteurl"`  and check

Comment: nice ! is it working for you ?

Comment: Awesome :) , have added it as an answer below. Could you please accept it so that it wont show up in the unanswered section ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your PS as below:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://siteURL/

$siteCol = $web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("ColumnName")

$subWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://siteurl/subsiteurl"

$spList = $subWeb.Lists["ListName"]

$spList.Fields.Add($siteCol)

$spList.Update()
```

You were getting an error because `$web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName` method is available on the `SPWeb` object but you were using it in the `SPSite` object. It wouldn't work, hence changed it from `SPSite` to `SPWeb`.